# Can i pull events from a facebook page using REST API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to pull events from any facebook page(given a page id) using REST Api. I am writing a server application and there is not facebook user login that we are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with an eternal Page Access Token via the `/{page_id}/events` edge.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events/

Comment: Which is fine but with appaccesstoken, can we pull events from any facebook page?

Comment: Its resolved. I was performing search operation, which was not permitted.